# Install Jobboarder v1.6.1, Joomla extention. Missing XML file

Tags: xml, joomla

I've downloaded the Jobboarder v1.6.1 and when i try to install it it gives a message "missing XML File".

Any help???

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the zip file, it contains the component and module files that need to be installed separately.